# React Native: Animation not working properly on android

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I have been trying to fix issue for the past 2 days, it works fine on iOS

```
constructor(){
  super();

  this.animation = new Animated.Value(0)

  this.state = {
    expanded: false,
  };
}
toggle(){
  let initialValue = this.state.expanded? 1 : 0 ,
     finalValue = this.state.expanded? 0 : 1

  this.setState({
     expanded: !this.state.expanded,
  });

  this.animation.setValue(initialValue)
  Animated.timing(
    this.animation,
    {
      toValue: finalValue,
    }
  ).start();
}

render(){
  return(
    <Animated.View style={{{flex: 1, marginTop: 28, paddingLeft: 25, transform: [{ scale: this.animation }, {perspective: 1000 }]}}}>
     ....
    </Animated.View>

  );
}
```

This component is child , used in parent like this: `<FeedBack ref={ref => this.feedback = ref}/>` without any conditions to check to show or not (because animation scale is set to Zero in the constructor, so no need)

the `toggle()` method is being called from parent when a button pressed.

Now `this works fine on iOS` , when component loads, the view is not there until a button is pressed (then scaled). but on `android` when the component loads, the view already there. When I press the button, the animated view disappears and re-appears (with animation scaling) and subsequent toggles work fine. The problem in android is that even though `initialValue` of the scale is Zero, the view is still there when it first loads.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This has been an issue with `react-native` on the android side for a while now (sigh). It seems that setting the value to `0` strips it of its characteristics, basically deeming it as `null` and then reverting to using its actual value once it had animated to `> 0`

A work around is to set animation like so
    `this.animation = new Animated.Value(0.01);`

You can follow the issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6278)

Comment: damn bro, what a waste of my time.. thanx for super sonic reply

Comment: Try the work around? keen to see how it goes. Could also animate the opacity if to hide it if its still there super small.

Comment: v0.63.3. Thanks. Earlier, width was just picking 0 or 1, not interpolating. Even putting 1 work for me, not just 0.01.........

     const parentRef = useRef(new Animated.Value(.01));

      Animated.timing(parentRef.current, {
        toValue,
        duration: 200,
        useNativeDriver: false,
        easing: Easing.bezier(.5,1.2,1,1)
      });

     <Anim...>
      style={[{
          width: parentRef.current.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [autoScale(100), autoScale(50)],
          }),
        }]}
     ></..>